# Any easy way to use Custom ScrollBars on a .Net Control

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a UserControl and I want to make custom scrolling.
Can I use the already built in Horizontal and Vertical ScrollBars without setting the AutoScroll flag to true?
I can Enable and define min and max value for both ScrollBars and I can see them on my control, but when clicking the buttons they don't move and in the scroll events I don't get any useful value.

```
            HorizontalScroll.Value = 0;
            VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
            HorizontalScroll.Minimum = 0;
            HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 900;
            VerticalScroll.Minimum = 0;
            VerticalScroll.Maximum = 600;
            HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;
            VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
            HorizontalScroll.SmallChange = 2;
            HorizontalScroll.LargeChange = 4;
            HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;
            VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
            this.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(PanelsHolder_Scroll);
```

in the Scroll Event I can't get any changes.
Any way to use the built-in without I have to add the scrolls controls manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see why not to use `AutoScroll`.

if you use the controllers, you'll have to move the controls by your self.

use `e.NewValue` to determined the value of the scroll. (in the event)

Comment: my control is mapping a huge image( I'm using the PaintBackGround to show it), and over the image I insert some controls( which I already need to manually change their location). Now the Control has a given Size..  the Size of the Image behind may change and most of the time will be larger that the Control. Is there a way I can tell the Control that it's real size is not the one it has in the UI so that the AutoScroll knows what size give to the Thumbs?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand, but you can put it alone in another separate userconrol, and then AutoScroll it..